# coupon collector and Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory

I need some help with my homework in probability.
I need to prove that if
$X(n) =$ the number of different coupons that the collector has in time $n$
then $X(n)$ represents a Markov chain.

I proved that 
$$P(X(m+1)=j)= \cases{
\frac{X(m)}{n}&\text{if $j=X(m)$}\\\
1-\frac{X(m)}{n}&\text{if $j=X(m)+1$}\\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.}$$
Now I need to show from there that $P(X(m+1)=j|X(m)=Km,\ldots ,X(0)=K0)=P(X(m+1)=j|X(m)=Km)$

thanks for the help.
benny.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, since you asked this 12 hours ago and nobody has responded yet, but I think you have it.  You have expressed $P(X(m+1) = j)$ in terms of the previous state $X(m)$ without reference to any of the prior states $X(m-1), X(m-2), \ldots, X(0)$.  That's enough to show that $X(m)$ is a Markov chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the upvotes on my comment, it looks like I didn't miss anything, so...

I think you have it.  You have expressed $P(X(m+1)=j)$  in terms of the previous state $X(m)$  without reference to any of the prior states $X(m−1),X(m−2), \ldots, X(0)$. That's enough to show that $X(m)$ is a Markov chain.

Comment: Must downvote, for the reasons explained in the other answer.

Comment: @did: Thanks for bringing this to my attention.  I agree with Byron's criticism of my answer.  Unfortunately, the software won't let me delete an accepted answer.

Comment: I know, this would be the OP's task. No big deal, anyway, and kudos from me for your prompt and written reaction.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is incomplete and potentially misleading, so 
I'm posting an extended comment.

First of all, there is something wrong with the OP's formula. The 
left hand side is a probability which is a non-random number while
the right hand side depends on the random variable $X(m)$. Probably what he means is

$$
P\big(X(m+1)=j\,|\, X(m)\big)= \cases{
\frac{X(m)}{n}&\text{if $X(m)=j$}\\[3pt]
1-\frac{X(m)}{n}&\text{if $X(m)=j-1$}\\[5pt]
0 &\text{otherwise}.}$$

This formula describes the conditional distribution of $X(m+1)$ given $X(m)$.
By definition, this  depends only on  $X(m)$ and not $X(m-1),\dots, X(1), X(0)$, 
and this is true *whether or not the process $X$ satisfies the Markov property*.

The OP is correct in asserting that to prove the Markov property, you must 
consider conditional  probabilities of the form
$$P(X(m+1)=j\,|\,X(m)=K_m,\ldots ,X(0)=K_0),$$
or alternatively joint probabilities of the form
$$P(X(m)=K_m,\ldots ,X(0)=K_0).$$

For the coupon collector's problem, this is a bit of a pain, but it is not terribly difficult 
and it has to be done to **prove** that $X$ is Markov.

---

**Added:** Here is a simple example that maybe explains my
objection a bit better.

Draw cards one at a time, without replacement,
from a well-shuffled deck. For $1\leq n\leq 52$, let
$X_n$ be the color of the card drawn at time $n$. This
is a stochastic process with state space ${\cal S}=\{R,B\}$.

For $1\leq n <52$, using exchangeability you find that
$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=j\,|\,X_n=i)$ is the $(i,j)$th entry in the
matrix

$$P= \pmatrix{{25\over 51}&{26\over 51}\\[3pt] {26\over 51}&{25\over 51}}.$$

So $(X_n)$ is time homogeneous, and has a "transition matrix" $P$ but,
nevertheless, it is **not**  Markov.

Why not? Well, for example 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_3=B\,|\,X_2=R,X_1=R)={26\over 50}\neq {26\over 51}=\mathbb{P}(X_3=B\,|\,X_2=R).$$

Comment: Thanks. It is a point that my students find confusing, so it's nice to have a concrete example of how things can go wrong.

Comment: +1.  Yes, nice example, and I see now where I went wrong.